# unique() function output in r not accurate - replicates values

Tags: r, unique

Used `unique()` function to extract unique timestamps from a large electrophysiology dataset. As per my knowledge, the value of `length(unique(dataset$time)` should have been 201; however, I am getting 1321.

Desired output:

```
unique(dataset$time)

  [1] -1.00 -0.99 -0.98 -0.97 -0.96 -0.95 -0.94 -0.93 -0.92 -0.91 -0.90 -0.89 -0.88 -0.87 -0.86
 [16] -0.85 -0.84 -0.83 -0.82 -0.81 -0.80 -0.79 -0.78 -0.77 -0.76 -0.75 -0.74 -0.73 -0.72 -0.71
 [31] -0.70 -0.69 -0.68 -0.67 -0.66 -0.65 -0.64 -0.63 -0.62 -0.61 -0.60 -0.59 -0.58 -0.57 -0.56
 [46] -0.55 -0.54 -0.53 -0.52 -0.51 -0.50 -0.49 -0.48 -0.47 -0.46 -0.45 -0.44 -0.43 -0.42 -0.41
 [61] -0.40 -0.39 -0.38 -0.37 -0.36 -0.35 -0.34 -0.33 -0.32 -0.31 -0.30 -0.29 -0.28 -0.27 -0.26
 [76] -0.25 -0.24 -0.23 -0.22 -0.21 -0.20 -0.19 -0.18 -0.17 -0.16 -0.15 -0.14 -0.13 -0.12 -0.11
 [91] -0.10 -0.09 -0.08 -0.07 -0.06 -0.05 -0.04 -0.03 -0.02 -0.01  0.00  0.01  0.02  0.03  0.04
[106]  0.05  0.06  0.07  0.08  0.09  0.10  0.11  0.12  0.13  0.14  0.15  0.16  0.17  0.18  0.19
[121]  0.20  0.21  0.22  0.23  0.24  0.25  0.26  0.27  0.28  0.29  0.30  0.31  0.32  0.33  0.34
[136]  0.35  0.36  0.37  0.38  0.39  0.40  0.41  0.42  0.43  0.44  0.45  0.46  0.47  0.48  0.49
[151]  0.50  0.51  0.52  0.53  0.54  0.55  0.56  0.57  0.58  0.59  0.60  0.61  0.62  0.63  0.64
[166]  0.65  0.66  0.67  0.68  0.69  0.70  0.71  0.72  0.73  0.74  0.75  0.76  0.77  0.78  0.79
[181]  0.80  0.81  0.82  0.83  0.84  0.85  0.86  0.87  0.88  0.89  0.90  0.91  0.92  0.93  0.94
[196]  0.95  0.96  0.97  0.98  0.99  1.00
```

The current output replicates this exact pattern and starts repeating the -1, -0.9 etc after reaching 1.0.
Any ideas on why this would happen?

Comment: it is a floating point number, so there would be precision involved i.e. what it is printing may not be the actual value.  You could use `dataset$time[!duplicated(round(dataset$time), 2))]`

Comment: Can you try if `unique(round(dataset$time, 2))` gives what you want?

Comment: thank you for your responses!  yes unique(round,dataset$time,2)) gave the correct response - so I think this was an issue with minor inconsistencies in the time stamps across my data.